Why Nx cli doesn't support generate pure javascript/typscript application?
I use @nx/js plugin from here: https://nx.dev/nx-api/js, but this plugin only support to generate a js/ts library, what if I want to generate a js/ts application?
nx g @nx/js:app my-app
>  NX   Unable to resolve @nx/js:app.


I don't need backend support, so @nx/node is not a choice.
I don't want to use any front-end framework such as react or angular.

What I need is just some frontend pages, pure js/html/css. which is the right plugin to use?
Thanks.
